# CursorLoader result selection

Tags: android, android-cursorloader

I've builded an AndroidApp which can display all my Contacts.
This is how my Cursor looks like:

```
public Cursor getAllContacts()
{
    CursorLoader cl = new CursorLoader(context, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
    return cl.loadInBackground();
}
```

It's working fine, but i want to build a second Cursor, which only can display Favorites I've set in SharedPreferences.

This is where i stuck at:

```
    public Cursor getFavContacts(){



    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

    Map<String, ?> allEntries = sharedPrefs.getAll();

    for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allEntries.entrySet()) {

        if(entry.getValue() instanceof Boolean) {
            Boolean isFav = (Boolean)entry.getValue();
            if(isFav) {
                Log.d("map values", entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue().toString());

                String[] split = entry.getKey().split("_");
                Log.d("splittedvalue", split[1]);
            }
        }
    }


    CursorLoader cl = new CursorLoader(context, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);


    Cursor cursor = cl.loadInBackground();
    if(cursor != null) {
        int count = cursor.getCount();
        Log.d("ContactsAdapter", "count: "  + count);



    }


    return cl.loadInBackground();
}
```

My log is showing correctly only the results i wanted to get. 
Now i want to tell the CursorLoader to get only my Favorites.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a solution!

```
    public Cursor getFavContacts(){

    String selection = null ;
    String[] split = null;
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

    Map<String, ?> allEntries = sharedPrefs.getAll();
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    final String COMMATA = ",";

    sb.append( ContactsContract.Contacts._ID+" IN (");


    for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allEntries.entrySet()) {

        if(entry.getValue() instanceof Boolean) {
            Boolean isFav = (Boolean)entry.getValue();
            if(isFav) {

                split = entry.getKey().split("_");
                sb.append(split[1]);
                sb.append(COMMATA);

            }
        }
    }
    int sblaenge = sb.length();
    sb.delete(sblaenge-1,sblaenge);
    sb.append( ")" );
    selection = sb.toString();
    Log.d(selection, selection);

    CursorLoader cl = new CursorLoader(context, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null,selection,null,ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);


    Cursor cursor = cl.loadInBackground();
    if(cursor != null) {
        int count = cursor.getCount();
        Log.d("ContactsAdapter", "count: "  + count);

    }
    return cl.loadInBackground();
}
```

I create an selection String which contains an sqlite query that gets the relevant contactids.

Answer (score 1):

You should add some `selection` to the `CursorLoader`.

If you want to get the favourites set by the phone (a.k.a the **starred** contacts in Android's contact list) the criteria would be `ContactsContract.Contacts.STARRED`.

If you want to display only specific contacts you singled out in your app (or favorited in your app), then I guess you already have those contacts' `_ID` or `DISPLAY_NAME` saved in your SharedPreferences, so you'll use this in the selection criteria.

For example to display the **starred** contacts your CursorLoader can look something like this:

```
CursorLoader cl = 
     new CursorLoader(context,
          ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
          null,
          ContactsContract.Contacts.STARRED = "1"
          null,
          ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
```

P.S. I haven't run the code above, but you should grasp the general idea from it.